# How do I retrieve decimals when rounding an average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my SQL statement

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(column_name), 100) 
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

The answer I retrieve is `3` with a possible range of numbers between `1 - 5` in 908 rows.

I need it to say `3.0` or `3.09`. Is this possible?

Comment: Whatever would be the point of specifying `100` for the length parameter of `ROUND`?

Comment: because you need 3 arguments in order for the round function to work I am also rounding it to the nearest 100th

Comment: But my point is you're never going to get 100 decimal places of precision in the first place, so `ROUND(,100)` won't affect anything. Just do `AVG(column_name)` and be done with it.

Comment: using `100` to with the ROUND function doesn't mean round to nearest 100th. It means you want 100 digits after the decimal point. See the examples at [MSDN: ROUND (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Comment: My apologies, I trying to get the answer provided by Guffa posted below. I was able to get to the point I reached when posting the question and without his help I do not believe I could have reached a solution. I do not understand why this was downvoted as a person who has not done research.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The average will have the same data type as the values, so cast the values:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(column_name AS FLOAT)), 2) FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

Comment: im not sure why I got the result that I have. just using the average I get 3, Using the float you provided i get 3.57 why is this...why did it not average or round to a 4?

Comment: @Skullomania ??, because you said you wanted to decimal digits on your question, why would you want it to round to 4 now?

Comment: I do not want to round it to 4. I was only curious why the original number was 3 instead of 4. It seems that I did not fully understand what the purpose of the float was in SQL. I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @Skullomania: Because casting to integer actually truncates rather than rounds.

Answer (score 5):

Im not sure if this will help you skullomania but try this

```
    SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(column_name as DECIMAL(10,2))) AS DECIMAL(10,2))FROM [table_name]
```

The float is an approximate, The decimal on the other hand will make it more of an exact, you may want to read up on floats math and decimals. I struggled at first with this and still feel lost at times. Hopefully this will help you out.

IN C#
        not sure if I can get in trouble for posting the answer here but have you tried converting it to a double and using a `ExecuteScalar()`

try this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     SqlConnection conn= sqlconnectionstring;
     SqlCommand cmd = new SQLCommand("SELECT STATEMENT",conn);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     conn.Open();
     Double result = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
     lblresult.text = "the result is " + result;
     conn.Dispose();
     cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Obadiah. This looks great! Please explain why you used cast twice.

Comment: If you only cast once then your result will have more than 3 decimal places...I thought this was more of what you were looking for. Didn't you wish to round to the nearest 100th?

Comment: That is correct. Thanks Obadiah! now I just need to figure out how to get this result in a variable for c#

Comment: just wondering, instead of `CAST(AVG(CAST))`, why couldn't you just do `CAST(AVG(col_name) AS DECIMAL(10,2))` ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking, but I think that you're wanting to have the number returned with additional precision.

You're wrapping the call in the [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function, but if your column's data type does not have any precision greater then 0 (e.g. int), you will need to CAST or CONVERT the data to another type first.

Here are some examples that illustrate several ways to [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) data to different types:

```
SELECT CAST(100 AS decimal(5, 2)) -- Gives you "100.00"
      ,CAST(100 AS float) --<== Gives you "100"
      ,CAST(100.0 AS float) --<== Gives you "100"
      ,CAST(100.01 AS float) --<== Gives you "100.01"
```

Also, check out [MSDN: Data Types (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).

Comment: The examples where you cast to `FLOAT` are not necessarily true though, they can vary with each execution. So, for example, `CAST(100 AS FLOAT)` might return `99.999999` or `100.000001`

Comment: While floating point numbers aren't always accurate when using them in calculations, I've never seen a number cast as float in SQL Server return a different result from one execution to the next. The inaccuracies of floating point numbers become more prevalent when compounding the inaccuracies over multiple iterations or calculations.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need to do a `ROUND` there, really. You could just convert your values to `DECIMAL`, like this:

```
SELECT AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,2),YourColumn)) 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: @Guffa - Yeap, that is true. Though op didn't specify the data type of his column. And, for the record, casting as `FLOAT` also brings along aproximations instead of exact values.

Comment: can you explain the reason for the (16,2) portion

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(AVG(column_name) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
```

It's show 100 as 100.00 
and
100.05 as 100.05

Answer (score 0):

There's a cool *1.0 trick.  Here are some examples of the trick.  int * decimal = decimal

```
with t as (select 1 as n union all
     select 4 as n)
select avg(n) -- 2
from t;

with t as (select 1.0 as n union all
     select 4.0 as n)
select avg(n) -- 2.5
from t;

with t as (select 1 as n union all
     select 4 as n)
select avg(n*1.0) -- 2.5
from t;
```