# AVG of a resultset

Tags: sql-server

Good morning.  SQL new guy here seeking some help.  I'm attempting to get the AVG of my resultset from a subquery.   The subquery works just fine and gives me the resultset I need, but I just cannot get the AVG of the resultset to work.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT) FROM   
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table2.item_no))   
FROM table1   
JOIN table2 ON table1.order_numb = table2.order_numb
WHERE user_so = 'paul'
AND order_date BETWEEN '9/20/2017'AND '9/20/2018'
GROUP BY table1.order_numb);
```

Here is a sample of the resultset from the subquery on its own that I'm trying to then turn around and get an AVG of:

```
216
181
163
156
144
144
143
133
129
129
120
114
113
112
112
109
108
104
103
99
98
98
98
98
98
97
97
97
96
96
94
94
94
93
93
```

Comment: What's wrong with the result you are getting? Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: So if the subquery returns 100, 200, 300, 400.  Do you want the entire query to return 250?

Comment: @sniperd Yes, that's my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(a_number) FROM   
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table2.item_no)) AS a_number  
FROM table1   
JOIN table2 ON table1.order_numb = table2.order_numb
WHERE user_so = 'paul'
AND order_date BETWEEN '9/20/2017'AND '9/20/2018'
GROUP BY table1.order_numb) AS the_subquery
```

I don't have the same tables with data, so here is a cut down working example:

```
SELECT AVG(a_number) FROM (
SELECT 100 AS a_number
UNION
SELECT 200 AS a_number
UNION
SELECT 300 AS a_number
UNION
SELECT 400 AS a_number
) AS the_subquery
```

It looks like you were missing that you need to alias the subquery and you want to `AVG` the alias of the value being returned in the subquery.

**update**

As per the comment, if you'd like the answer to be rounded to 2 decimal points you will need to `CAST` it to a different data type, like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(a_number AS FLOAT)), 2) FROM   
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table2.item_no)) AS a_number  
FROM table1   
JOIN table2 ON table1.order_numb = table2.order_numb
WHERE user_so = 'paul'
AND order_date BETWEEN '9/20/2017'AND '9/20/2018'
GROUP BY table1.order_numb) AS the_subquery
```

or for others without access to the table:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(a_number AS FLOAT)), 2) FROM (
SELECT 100 AS a_number
UNION
SELECT 200 AS a_number
UNION
SELECT 300 AS a_number
UNION
SELECT 403 AS a_number
) AS the_subquery
```

You can read more about how `ROUND`, `AVG`, and `CAST` work here: [How do I retrieve decimals when rounding an average in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237477/how-do-i-retrieve-decimals-when-rounding-an-average-in-sql)

Comment: My original subquery returns 20,585 rows (which I need the avg of all those rows).  With your query wouldn't I have to create a SELECT/UNION statement for each of those rows?  Sorry, still trying to wrap my head around some of the syntax and logic.

Comment: @Drezriel Nope, that was just an example using a simple subquery.  Just copy/paste the top query and yours should just work.  :)

Comment: @Drezriel keep 20,585 rows in one temp table on top of it take count it will work i guess

Comment: @sniperd That worked!  Pardon my ignorance, but why would adding an alias to the subquery make the whole thing work?  Now my other question is just because I cheated and copy/pasted the data into excel and it gave me an average of 5.99.  The AVG just gave me an answer of 5.  How would I update the query to not round down?

Comment: When you want to reference stuff in the subquery you need to alias it, otherwise SQL doesn't really know what you want.  It's just part of the syntax of the language.  You can think of it like you are making the subquery a temporary table (but it's _not_ a temp table, that has a specific meaning in SQL).  If you want to round with 2 decimal points, I'll update my answer in a moment.  And if that works for you, please accept my answer by clicking the little check mark :)

Comment: @sniperd Thank you very much.  The updated query returned 6 where I was looking for 5.99.  I updated the )),2) to )),3) and it gave me 5.998.  So I won't waste anymore of your time and try to figure out why that worked over the ,2 decimal places call.  Thank you again!

Comment: @Drezriel happy to help, and welcome to StackOverflow :)  A _lot_ of coding (and SQL) is hitting the go button a lot and then figuring out why it didn't work.  SQL has some weirdness to it where you simply have to ask somebody else that has done it before.  Good luck!

Comment: To test how the alias fixes this, try the subquery with/without alias- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1; SELECT COUNT(*) as val1 FROM TABLE1;

Check the column headers in the output.