# Need help creating a view that will give me average goals scored and conceded per game for for EPL teams

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with coming up with the right code to calculate the average goals scored and conceded per game and rounding it to the 2nd decimal place (i.e. 2.34 goals per game). I have two tables EPLTeams2023 which contains one column with all the team names. I have another table called Matches_Duplicate which has match results. The columns for that table are MatchID, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HomeScore,AwayScore, and MatchDate

Basically I want a view that has the following columns: Team - AvgGoalsScoredPerGame - AvgGoalsConcededPerGame - TotalMatchesPlayed

Here is the query I tried but it doesn't seem to give me the average to two decimal places and I am not sure if it is pulling in the correct scores:

```sql
CREATE VIEW EPLTeamStats2023 AS
SELECT
    t.Team AS TeamName,
    ROUND(AVG(goals_scored), 2) AS AvgGoalsScored,
    ROUND(AVG(goals_conceded), 2) AS AvgGoalsConceded,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalMatchesPlayed
FROM
    EPLTeams2023 t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        HomeTeam AS Team,
        HomeScore AS goals_scored,
        AwayScore AS goals_conceded
    FROM
        Matches_Duplicate
    WHERE
        HomeTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND HomeScore IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayScore IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate >= '2023-08-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        AwayTeam AS Team,
        AwayScore AS goals_scored,
        HomeScore AS goals_conceded
    FROM
        Matches_Duplicate
    WHERE
        HomeTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND HomeScore IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayScore IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate >= '2023-08-01'
) m ON t.Team = m.Team
GROUP BY
    t.Team;
```

Comment: Please improve your question according to the instructions in this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why all those column `IS NOT NULL` conditions? Aren't those columns declared as `NOT NULL`?!? A game with an unknown (NULL) team makes no sense.

Comment: What DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, etc...) are you using? You have a query that looks perfectly reasonable. What do you mean by "doesn't seem to give me the average to two decimal places" ... what is it giving you?

Comment: @jarlh I have those column IS NOT NULL because the API I am pulling from has all the games for the whole season generated so I only wanted to pull in the games that have been played if that makes sense?

Comment: @Error_2646 I am on SQL Server Management Studio, pretty new to SQL. When I run that query it is giving me results like 2.00, 1.00, 0.00 which I know arent accurate because I did the quick match and for example Arsenal FC are averaging 2.17 goals per game so far

Comment: FYI SQL Server Management Studio is not a database engine, it is an IDE. It's much more helpful to specify the version of the database engine you're running (eg 2012, 2019, 2022, etc.). For future reference, you can post the results of `select @@version` in your ticket if you're not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The average will have the same data type as the values, so cast the values.

This will be your final view:

```
CREATE VIEW EPLTeamStats2023 AS
SELECT
    t.Team AS TeamName,
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(goals_scored AS FLOAT)), 2) AS AvgGoalsScored,
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(goals_conceded AS FLOAT)), 2) AS AvgGoalsConceded,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalMatchesPlayed
FROM
    EPLTeams2023 t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        HomeTeam AS Team,
        HomeScore AS goals_scored,
        AwayScore AS goals_conceded
    FROM
        Matches_Duplicate
    WHERE
        HomeTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND HomeScore IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayScore IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate >= '2023-08-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        AwayTeam AS Team,
        AwayScore AS goals_scored,
        HomeScore AS goals_conceded
    FROM
        Matches_Duplicate
    WHERE
        HomeTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayTeam IS NOT NULL
        AND HomeScore IS NOT NULL
        AND AwayScore IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate IS NOT NULL
        AND MatchDate >= '2023-08-01'
) m ON t.Team = m.Team
GROUP BY
    t.Team;
```

Sources:

1. [How do I retrieve decimals when rounding an average in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237542/10467804)
2. [AVG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: That worked thank you so much!!

Comment: @IanW please upvote and accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little alternative to your code:

```sql
CREATE VIEW EPLTeamStats2023 AS
SELECT  t.Team AS TeamName
,   ROUND(AVG(goals_scored * 1.0), 2) AS AvgGoalsScored
,   ROUND(AVG(goals_conceded * 1.0), 2) AS AvgGoalsConceded
,   COUNT(*) AS TotalMatchesPlayed
FROM    EPLTeams2023 t
INNER JOIN Matches_Duplicate d
    ON  t.team IN (d.HomeTeam, AwayTeam)
WHERE   HomeTeam IS NOT NULL
AND AwayTeam IS NOT NULL
AND HomeScore IS NOT NULL
AND AwayScore IS NOT NULL
AND MatchDate >= '2023-08-01'
GROUP BY t.Team;
```

It might be a little slower depending on the indexes, but looks a bit shorter, and there's less chance of copy paste errors.
Basically, you join the duplicate table once and calculate the averages as before.

Also, i prefer to do: `goals_scored * 1.0` to get the values to become "averagable", but it's probably same as CASTing.